# how to modify jquery photo-manager script to use more boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, droppable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to draw images into several boxes instead of the trash box. I tried, but I am having a hard time solving this. Does anybody have an idea, how to approach this matter?
This is how I tried it:

changed html:

```
<div>
<div id="drop1" class="drop">
 <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Trash</span> Box 1</h4>
</div>

<div id="drop2" class="drop">
 <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Trash</span> Box 2</h4>
</div>
</div>
```

the droppable method:

```
// let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
  $dropp.droppable({
    accept: "#gallery > li",
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
     deleteImage(ui.draggable);
  }
 });
// let the gallery be droppable as well, accepting items from the trash
 $gallery.droppable({
  accept: ".drop li",
  activeClass: "custom-state-active",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    recycleImage(ui.draggable);
  }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Reksio/HvGEc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Why does nobody take a look at this???
I found a solution by myself again, but it has not proved satisfactory. It's now possible to draw to each box and back, but not between boxes.

```
$(function() {
// there's the gallery and the trash
  var $gallery = $("#gallery"),
  $dropp = $(".drop");
// let the gallery items be draggable
  $("li", $gallery).draggable({
  cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
  revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
  containment: "document",
  helper: "clone",
  cursor: "move"
  });
// let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
  $('.drop').droppable({
    accept: "#gallery > li",
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
     deleteImage(ui.draggable,$(this));
    }
  });
// let the gallery be droppable as well, accepting items from the trash
 $gallery.droppable({
  accept: ".drop li",
  activeClass: "custom-state-active",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    recycleImage(ui.draggable);
  }
 });
 // image deletion function
   var recycle_icon = "<a href='link/to/recycle/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Rausnehmen' class='ui-icon ui-icon-refresh'>Löschen</a>";
   function deleteImage(item,droppp) {
     item.fadeOut(function() {
       var $list = $("ul", droppp).length ?
       $("ul", droppp) :
       $("<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo(droppp);
       item.find("a.ui-icon-trash").remove();
       item
       .appendTo($list)
       .fadeIn(function() {
         item
         .animate({ width: "48px" })
         .find("img")
         .animate({ height: "36px" });
       });
     });
    }
    function recycleImage($item) {
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      $item
      .find("a.ui-icon-refresh")
      .remove()
      .end()
      .css("width", "96px")
      .find("img")
      .css("height", "72px")
      .end()
      .appendTo($gallery)
      .fadeIn();
     });
    }
 // image preview function, demonstrating the ui.dialog used as a modal window
  function viewLargerImage($link) {
   var src = $link.attr("href"),
   title = $link.siblings("img").attr("alt"),
   $modal = $("img[src$='" + src + "']");
   if($modal.length) {
     $modal.dialog("open");
   } else {
  var img = $("<img alt='" + title + "' width='384' height='288' style='display: none; padding: 8px;' />")
    .attr("src", src).appendTo("body");
    setTimeout(function() {
    img.dialog({
      title: title,
      width: 400,
      modal: true
    });
    }, 1);
   }
  }
// resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
 $("ul.gallery > li").click(function(event) {
   var item = $(this),
   $target = $(event.target);
   if($target.is("a.ui-icon-trash")) {
     deleteImage(item);
   } else if($target.is("a.ui-icon-zoomin")) {
    viewLargerImage($target);
   }
   return false;
 });
});
```